# OleDb Excel join with unnamed columns from c#

Tags: c#, excel, join, oledb

I'm trying to perform a join between two sheets using ACE.OleDb. Columns are unnamed so I can't use the name of the column in the ON condition.

ConnectionString used is:

```
String.Format("Provider = {0}; Data Source = {1}; Extended Properties = \"{2}\" ", "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0", file, "Excel 8.0;HDR=YES");
```

With named columns something like this works great:

```
select * from [sheet1$] inner join [sheet2$] on [sheet1$].[ID] = [sheet2$].[ID]
```

¿Any way to do it without the named column ID? Of course I know the index of the column, it will be always the first.

I have tried something like this with no success:

```
select * from [sheet1$] inner join [sheet2$] on [sheet1$].[$A] = [sheet2$].[$A]
```

Result is:

```
Syntax error in JOIN operation
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I want to join two sheets without any specification. Like in MSSQL "select tbl_1.id, tbl_2.id from tbl_1 left join tbl_2 on 1 = 1"

Answer (score 0):

To use unnamed columns, you have to set `HDR=NO` in the connectionstring.

> "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\myfile.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO\""

With this setting, every column gets names like F1, F2, F3...

You can use them like this:

```
select * from [sheet1$] inner join [sheet2$] on [sheet1$].[F1] = [sheet2$].[F2]
```

The auto-naming for the columns refers to the columns you are using as a table. So if you say `select * from [sheet1$B1] ...` The column `B` will be available as `F1`